# New ColumnSet(true) not returning all columns in a query

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a query that is generically used across to return data from different entities within the same plugin. In the query I have chosen to return all columns using new ColumnSet(true).

For the most part this works without any issues, but i've just come across one entity where it is failing to bring back a number of fields. These fields are calculated using a separate plugin but the values definitely appear to be held on the records themselves, as they are visible on the form and in views. However they are not returned in the query.

I tried as a long shot to create my own record via importing, where I set those values myself rather than via the plugin. These values do get found when done this way, but for the other records they are still missing.

I have copied my query below in case someone can see something wrong with it.

```
//set up query for entity
                QueryExpression query;
                query = new QueryExpression();
                query.EntityName = entityName;
                query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
                query.PageInfo.ReturnTotalRecordCount = true;

                //get the results                    
                EntityCollection SourceRecords = new EntityCollection();

                int pageNumber = 1;
                RetrieveMultipleRequest req;
                RetrieveMultipleResponse resp = new RetrieveMultipleResponse(); ;

                do
                {
                    query.PageInfo.Count = 5000;
                    query.PageInfo.PagingCookie = (pageNumber == 1) ? null : resp.EntityCollection.PagingCookie;
                    query.PageInfo.PageNumber = pageNumber++;

                    req = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
                    req.Query = query;
                    resp = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)SourceOrgService.Execute(req);
                    SourceRecords.Entities.AddRange(resp.EntityCollection.Entities);
                }
                while (resp.EntityCollection.MoreRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Query itself looks fine, so you're running into one of two problems.

1. Your plugin that is calculating the values, is not getting triggered, is not updating the values it calculates, or is being triggered after the currently executing plugin  (there is a "Rank" value when you register a plugin step, that controls the order of which the steps are executed, that could be your issue.  Need more information about the plugin steps and how they are registered).
2. You have some sort of field level security where the user the plugin is executing as, doesn't have rights to the calculated fields.